# how to grep this line

Tags: linux, grep

This is a content of file `test`

```
>-----------------max------------------

>-----------------abc

def

<------------------mnc------------------

jkl
```

Here I want to grep the line that contains `<` `>` symbol

I tried this method

```
[max@localhost ~]$ grep \> \< test

grep: <: No such file or directory

test:>-----------------max------------------

test:>-----------------abc
```

but it's not working what should i do now?

Comment: You considered that the input for grep looks like this: `grep PATTERN FILE FILE FILE FILE ...`?

Comment: @Bobby PATTERN is this only `>` `<` i know these are redirect symbol, but how to remove the special meaning of this symbol, i thought that putting slash in front of this symbol remove the special meaning, but i am wrong in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could do like this:

```
grep -e ">" -e "<" test
```

Answer (score 2):

Always try to use single quotes with grep:

> grep '>\|<' test

The above example also makes use of the **OR** (|) operator.

You might also want to match these symbols only at the beginning of the line, in which case you'd want to do this:

> grep '^(>\|<)' test

( `( )` make a group, `^` signifies the beginning of the line )

Comment: `grep '>\|<' test` This is working for me... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

The symbols \< and > respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a word.